# Spring mvc controller not mapping POST'd JSON to object

Tags: javascript, json, spring, maven, backbone.js

My client side javascript application uses backbone.js.  Here's where I POST the JSON:

```
function testREST() {
    var model;
    cfd.init($('#email').val() + ':');

    model = new cfd.UserModel({
        email: 'test@example.com',
        fName: 'Test',
        lName: 'Dude',
        heardHow: 21,
        isDeleted: 0
    });

    model.save();
}
```

**This is POSTing to my controller, but getting a 400 because of the controller parameters.**

Here is the JSON payload:

```
{ "email" : "test@example.com",
  "fName" : "Test",
  "heardHow" : 21,
  "isDeleted" : 0,
  "lName" : "Dude"
}
```

Here's the controller:

```
@Controller
public class PostController {

    @Inject
    private UserRepository users;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/app/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody void insertUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        System.out.println("POST SAYS HI: " + user.getfName());
        users.save(user);
    }
}
```

This works if I remove:

```
@RequestBody User user
```

But naturally I need it.

User class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email = "";

    @Column(name="fname")
    private String fName = "";

    @Column(name="lname")
    private String lName = "";

    @Column(name="heardhow")
    private int heardHow = 0;

    @Column(name="isdeleted")
    private boolean isDeleted = false;

    public User() {

    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getfName() {
        return fName;
    }

    public void setfName(String fName) {
        this.fName = fName;
    }

    public String getlName() {
        return lName;
    }

    public void setlName(String lName) {
        this.lName = lName;
    }

    public int getHeadHow() {
        return heardHow;
    }

    public void setHeadHow(int headHow) {
        this.heardHow = headHow;
    }

    public boolean isDeleted() {
        return isDeleted;
    }

    public void setDeleted(boolean isDeleted) {
        this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
    }
}
```

I have the following maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>         
</dependency>
```

I have also included the following in my spring-config.xml:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

I'm patterning my implementation off of the following:

```
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestmapping-consumes
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Post your `User` class.

Comment: Post the JSON that gets sent to the server.

Comment: Either use `org.codehause.jackson` (which is Jackson1) or `com.fasterxml.jackson` (which is Jackson2) using both at the same time might give strange results.

Comment: @M.Deinum I posted the User class and removed codehause.jackson

Comment: @MikeR I posted the JSON

Comment: It's just like the request is not falling into this controller method...

Comment: If I remove the @RequestBody annotation, then a blank User parametrized into the method.  Not very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your `User` class. The property `headHow` should be `heardHow`. The JSON uses the property `heardHow`. The typo may be causing the Jackson mapper to fail when data binding - causing the 400.

Update: I answered this when the original question contained the code for the `User`

Comment: That is an amazing catch, one I would never have found.  Unfortunately the issue is not resolved.

Comment: And I put the User.class back in the question

Comment: Your getters and setters still contain the typo: `getHeadHow` and `setHeadHow`

Comment: According to [this artictle](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/02/entry_443.html) the mapper uses the getter method to determine the property name. So the property name is still `headHow` not `heardHow` - even though you've updated the field name itself.

Comment: Yup, that was it.  You know I stared at all this for 4 hours and couldn't see that?  Thank you Will!  Coincidentally I also had to rename isDeleted to getIsDeleted and setDeleted to setIsDeleted.